# javax.jnlp.BasicService showDocument returns false

Tags: java, java-web-start

The showDocument(URL url) method of javax.jnlp.BasicService always returns false for the below url. Which is a functioning URL.
http://www.star.bristol.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/topcat-full.jnlp

I have tried escaping the url but still the method just returns false.

Any help please?
Thanks

Comment: So to clarify a few things. 1) `isWebBrowserSupported()` returns `true` on that system? 2) Other (non JNLP) URLs return `true`? 3) The action on that JNLP **fails** to launch the application? .. BTW - A JNLP based URL when passed to the method should be handed directly back to the Java Web Start client (an app. made by Oracle). I'm not sure if that implied that the `BasicService` would recognise it and cut the browser out of the action completely. If not, we have the complication that most browsers will no longer automatically launch JNLP files, instead forcing the user to download them. ..

Comment: .. or in some case (I suspect) completely ignoring the request to open the JNLP. I'd recommend searching the bug database for anything similar. BTW 2, try using `Desktop.browse(URL)` on that same URL and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this question rather accidentally, and I see it is already four years old, so @user1472672 is likely no longer holding his breath for that.

Anyway, for any later passers-by:

The problem is most likely the "~" char.
It needs to be encoded as %7E  (percent 7E)

At least that once solved it for me.